# how to get the text enclosed by quotations using php

Tags: php, string

So I have a pretty large dump file that I have to extract specific content from it.
The file has record each containing specific numbers enclosed by `"`. Bellow is a sample part of the file:

```
Ali Rabi (CustomerId=["3453456"]) // need to get: 3453456
Mohammad Reza Saberi (CustomerId=["12328"]) // need to get: 12328
```

Currently I read line by line and get the IDs as bellow. the code works fine and I get the result I want:

```
$cid = substr($row, strpos($row, '[') +2, strpos($row, ']')-strpos($row, '[')-2);
echo $cid;
```

But doesn't PHP have a function for this? getting the string enclosed by some delimiters?

Comment: Have a look at Regular Expressions; this Simple RegEx would extract the ID: `/([1-9]+)/`

Comment: Have you tried with regex? if(preg_match_all('/\"(.*?)\"/',$long_string_here,$match))

Comment: here it is `(?<=")\d+(?=")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your records look like the ones you've mentioned, I think it's the perfect place where you could use regular expressions.

Regular Expressions help you to create and find patterns in a given String.

For your case, you could probably use :

```
if (preg_match("/[0-9]+/", "Ali Rabi (CustomerId=[\"3453456\"])", $matches)) {
  echo "Match was found <br />";
  echo $matches[0];
}
```

The preg_match() function helps you to find the matches. The first param for this function is the pattern you're looking for. In your case you're looking for a set of continuous digits each of which can range from 0-9.

So, for a single digit we use [0-9]. Adding a `+` after [0-9] means that there needs to be atleast one digit in the match. Hence, [0-9]+ as the regular expression.

Read more about regular expressions in php : http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

Comment: `foreach($matches[0] as $entry){echo $entry.'; ';}`  would be the code to get alle the ID of the Array

Comment: ^^ This is the ideal way to go about finding all matches, all that needs to be done is to pass the whole dump as the second parameter of `preg_match()` and you'll have all the matches in the `$matches` array.

Comment: @ShivamVerma your regex would match also the numbers which was present outside the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php preg_match_all("/([1-9]+)/",$yourtext, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); ?>
```

$result contains all Matches.
Further Infomartion: http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use str_replace to remove the "

```
$cid = str_replace('"','',$row);
```